# Automatically submit values to server

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I am planning to build an automatic checker extension for a webmail application for Chrome; something that I have done before, but now I have a problem.

At the login site, I have the following login form:

```
<form name="form" action="./" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="8efe33...">
<input type="hidden" name="_task" value="login"><input type="hidden" name="_action" value="login"><input type="hidden" name="_timezone" id="rcmlogintz" value="_default_"><input type="hidden" name="_dstactive" id="rcmlogindst" value="_default_"><input type="hidden" name="_url" id="rcmloginurl" value=""><table summary="" border="0"><tbody><tr><td class="title"><label for="rcmloginuser">Username</label>
</td>
<td class="input"><input name="_user" id="rcmloginuser" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="title"><label for="rcmloginpwd">Password</label>
</td>
<td class="input"><input name="_pass" id="rcmloginpwd" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" type="password"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<p style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" class="button mainaction" value="Login" /></p>

</form>
```

As you can see, it has the fields '_user', and '_pass' for username and password accordingly, and the submit button does a './' action of type POST.

./ means the current file, which is index.php in this specific situation.

This means, as far as I understand, calling:

```
email_server.com/index.php?_user=some_username&_pass=some_password
```

will submit these values (just like filling the login credentials and hitting the 'Login' button). Instead, it simply fills in the _user value and _pass is still empty, not to talk about the fact that it doesn't try to login at all.

I've done this at the past and it worked perfectly. Am I missing something at this situation?

Comment: You need to post the values, when you are putting them in the URL and calling them you use the `GET` method which is something different.

Comment: Your the form generated on client side or server side?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles

Comment: @user9379 : I need one confirmation,are you trying to do some validation on your data before submitting or you want to submit the data automatically after some scheduled time ? because your Title sounds different than what you are trying to explaing

Comment: @dreamweiver I don't want to do some validation, I want the extension to have a 'Go to your inbox' button that will make the browser go to a url like this: 'https://some_server.com/redirect.php?login=my_login&pass=my_pass', where my_login and my_pass variables got by the user from the extension's option page (in an unrelated topic)

Comment: @user9379 : you can add session variable for username and password in the form which accepts user credentials and pass on the same in the traget URL. Well i`m not so sure abt the security concerns related in my answer.hope so this would help you

Comment: @dreamweiver but isn't this what am I doing? Can you please post here an example URL?

Comment: @user9379 : First you need to store the value in session varibales **session['username']=$username** and **session['password']=$password** (assuming that $username and $password will contain username and password respectively). Now you can construct the target url as  **$url="email_server.com/index.php?_user=".session['username']."&_pass=".session['password']**

Comment: @user9379 : sorry about the syntax error in above comment,its $_SESSION['username'] and $_SESSION['password'] . before setting session cvariables you have to start the session like this **session_start()**

Answer (score 0):

You will have to know where that form sends its data before you can send it, because you will have to emulate a form. cURL has the ability to send POST and GET data to the server via many different option settings. check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for all the settings. Anything that start with CURLOPT_POST... is a good bet.

Comment: Hello Nima and thanks for the suggestion, but I do not own the server with this login form. I am client-side and I should send the user to a URL that will allow him to automatically login to the site.

Comment: only way is cURL! ;) learn more about cURL it will help you in this case :)